# How to get that output with nested for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How to get that output with nested for python
I've tried but haven't got that kind of output

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(i, i+10):
        print(j, end = " ")
    print()
```

Comment: You are correct. I copied the code from my editor and I guess I lost the indentation on pasting. Fixing now

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `list` then in each iterate print `list` then add one to all element like below:

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for _ in range(10):
    print(*lst, sep=' ')
    lst = [l+1 for l in lst]
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

Comment: what is the sep=' ' syntax for?

Comment: @BayuSatrio, this is `*lst` pass all element from `lst` to print but you need space between elements then you can add space between elements with `sep=" "`

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://realpython.com/lessons/sep-end-and-flush/) help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0
while i!=10:
    c = ''
    for j in range(i,i+10):
        c = c + str(j) + " "
    print(c)
    i+=1
```

Comment: Consider explaining why this code solves the problem